Prove: Derivative of a Trace is the Trace of a Derivative
For some matrix $X$, I am trying to prove that:
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \text{Tr}(X) = \text{Tr}\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}X\right) $$
Here is my logic:
For an $n×n$ matrix $X$:
$$ \text{Tr}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ii} $$
where $x_{ii}$ are the diagonal elements of $X$.
Making this subtitution:
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \text{Tr}(X) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ii} $$
In my opinion, the key part of this proof relies on the fact the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives:
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \text{Tr}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{d\theta} x_{ii} $$
In my eyes, this is sufficient justification to conclude that:
$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \text{Tr}(X) = \text{Tr}\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}X\right) $$
Is this the correct mathematical logic?

There's nothing wrong with this reasoning. More generally, every linear function commutes with taking derivatives. This is a consequence of the chain rule.
